# Add No-Required params to custom REST API

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I made a custom REST API on Magento 2. I want some params to be required and other to be no required or accept **null**. I have the next code:

**Api/Order/ShippingInterface**

```
  /**
* API00004. Envío de Pedido
* Url Path: /rest/V1/orders/sap/shipping
* Se mandará a este servicio la información cuando un pedido ya ha
* sido enviado.
*
* @api
* @param string IdPedido
* @param string ControlNumber
* @param string UrlFile
* @param string DecodeFile
* @param string[] Trackings
* @return string JSON con Mensaje de Confirmación o Error.
*/
public function set(
  $IdPedido = null,
  $ControlNumber = null,
  $UrlFile = null,
  $DecodeFile = null,
  $Trackings = null
);
```

**Model/Api/Order/Shipping.php**

```
/**
* API00004. Envío de Pedido
* Url Path: /rest/V1/orders/sap/shipping
* Se mandará a este servicio la información cuando un pedido ya ha
* sido enviado.
*
* @api
* @param string IdPedido
* @param string ControlNumber
* @param string UrlFile
* @param string DecodeFile
* @param string[] Trackings
* @return string JSON con Mensaje de Confirmación o Error.
*/
public function set(
  $IdPedido = null,
  $ControlNumber = null,
  $UrlFile = null,
  $DecodeFile = null,
  $Trackings = null
){ ... }
```

But when I send a Json like:

> {"IdPedido":null,"ControlNumber":null,"UrlFile":null,"DecodeFile":null,"Trackings":null}

It returns me the next error:

> message":"One or more input exceptions have occurred.","errors":[{"message":"%fieldName is a required field.","parameters":{"fieldName":"IdPedido"}},{"message":"%fieldName is a required field.","parameters":{"fieldName":"ControlNumber"}},{"message":"%fieldName is a required field.","parameters":{"fieldName":"UrlFile"}},{"message":"%fieldName is a required field.","parameters":{"fieldName":"DecodeFile"}},{"message":"%fieldName is a required field.","parameters":{"fieldName":"Trackings"}}]

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post a code of your webapi.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Open file

```
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/etc/webapi.xml
```

and inside try to locate this code

```
<route url="/V1/carts/mine/shipping-information" method="POST">
    <service class="Magento\Checkout\Api\ShippingInformationManagementInterface" method="saveAddressInformation"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="self" />
    </resources>
    <data>
        <parameter name="cartId" force="true">%cart_id%</parameter>
    </data>
</route>
```

You see, specifically inside the `<data>` tag, the `<parameter>` tag has attribute named `force` and it is equal to `true` in this case.

I'm inclined to say that this is the way do to it, in your case you will of course set `force="false"`. Though, I have never tried this myself to be honest.

Anyway, open this link

```
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-to-web-service.html
```

and further click on `Sample webapi.xml file`

and I think you will find similar recommendations of XML handling this.

I hope this help, good luck.

Comment: This is not the answer of question, this process is used to override parameter values each time api gets hit.